# GPT formatted drive in Legacy Boot MBR system not readable

Tags: boot, partitioning, mbr, gpt, removable

My Windows 8 system only contains MBR partitions.
I added a big disk internally and formatted it with GPT (given the MBR Constraints of 2TB) and copied some videos.

When I plugged this disk in a different similar system and to the system itself, it gets recognized as "Removable Disk" and the content is not readable.

I formatted the disks with partition wizard. https://www.partitionwizard.com/

But even using Partition Wizard, the disks are not recognized.
What should I do to get access to the GPT disk?

---

**your questions:**
Was the disk connected directly to SATA in all cases, or were you using any kind of USB-SATA adapter on either machine?

I tried both ways, connect internally and with a USB3 drive. In the original system, where I did the format: Both work.

In the different system/computer: in both connection types, the disk is not recognized, but treated as unreadable media drive.

"Please clarify your specific problem": Disk not recognized on Target system.
What I exactly need: Disk is readable on target system.

@Peregrino69 Yes, correct the boot system remains legacy boot, on an MBR Disk.
I need the GPT driver on the target system.

**First hint:**
It appears that partition Wizard installs a GPT driver on this legacy (MBR) system, when formatting the disk as GPT.

This driver, however, is not present in the target system.

Comment: Please EDIT your question and add the following information: Operating system you are using. With which tool(s) did you do the formatting and partitioning and what filesystem did you use for the formatting.

Comment: Not possible: [Microsoft article](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/bringup/switch-from-legacy-mbr-disk-to-gpt-disk-with-windows-10) says: "Legacy MBR boot is not able to recognize GUID Partition Table (GPT) disks. It requires an active partition and supporting BIOS to facilitate access to disk. OLD and limited on HDD size and number of partitions. On UEFI firmware systems, it requires CSM enabled and loaded into memory to facilitate active partition booting." Whatever you did was invalid and resulted in an invalid disk.

Comment: Actually OP isn't saying that he's trying to boot from a GPT disk, just access it. Microsoft states in https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/windows-and-gpt-faq Vista, WinSer2003 and all later versions "can use GPT partitioned disks for data" (both 32 and 64bit), so a Win8 should be able to. They further state that mixing MBR- and GPT-partitioned disks is supported.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Was the disk connected directly to SATA in all cases, or were you using any kind of USB-SATA adapter on either machine?

Comment: In the future please [edit] your original question rather than adding information in answers. This is a Question and Answer site and we work differently from conventional forums. It might help to take the [tour].

Comment: Windows XP was the last version that could not read gpt partitioned data drives with standard default install, even XP could add gpt read but only by slip streaming driver  during install. Windows only boots from gpt with UEFI, but even a BIOS/MBR install will read another drive that is gpt. Your issue is probably Windows fast start up/hibernation. https://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/unable-to-mount-windows-10-partition-it-is-in-an-unsafe-state & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation